# Advanced SQL update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
+------+-----------+----------+
|  ID  |  Column1  |  Column2 |  
+------+-----------+----------+
|    1 |      x    |      a   |
|    2 |      x    |      b   |
|    3 |      x    |      c   |
|    4 |      y    |      d   |
|    5 |      y    |      e   |
|    6 |      y    |      f   |    
+------+-----------+----------+
```

I am trying to replace the duplicated Column1 value by " ";

So like this

```
+------+-----------+----------+
|  ID  |  Column1  |  Column2 |  
+------+-----------+----------+
|    1 |      x    |      a   |
|    2 |           |      b   |
|    3 |           |      c   |
|    4 |      y    |      d   |
|    5 |           |      e   |
|    6 |           |      f   |    
+------+-----------+----------+
```

This is what I tried:

```
Update #temp 

SET status = '' 
where id != (select top 1 id from #temp where status != (select min(status) from #temp));
```

This is a temp table. I am using SQL server

Comment: top is not a mysql statement and nor are #tables are you sure this mysql and not sqlserver?

Comment: Don't do it!  You can do this transformation in the application.  But if the value is really "x" or "y", don't remove it.

Comment: to add to @P.Salmon 's comment `#temp` is also SQL Server syntax for creating a temporary table.

Comment: What should happen if the values in `column1` go `x, x, y, y, x, x` *(when order by `id`)*?  Do you want to keep a single `x`, or keep two *(the first one in each "group")*?

Comment: What happens if you update rows 2 and 3 and then delete row 1? Lost information

Comment: @P.Salmon - It's in a temp table, information is about to be lost anyway...

Comment: Sorry about the misinformation. I am using a temp table and SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what benefit you will get by updating this, but still you can do it like following using `CTE`.

```
;with cte as
(
 select 
    id,column1,column2 ,row_number() over (partition by column1 order by id) rn
 from #temp
)
update c
set c.column1=''
from cte c
where rn>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script by using IIF() IN Sql server

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#t')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t;

;WITH CTE(ID,Column1,Column2)
AS
(
SELECT 1 ,'x','a' UNION ALL  
SELECT 2 ,'x','b' UNION ALL  
SELECT 3 ,'x','c' UNION ALL  
SELECT 4 ,'y','d' UNION ALL  
SELECT 5 ,'y','e' UNION ALL  
SELECT 6 ,'y','f' 
)
SELECT * INTO #t FROM CTE c
```

Before Table Update

```
SELECT * FROM #t
```

Update Query

```
 ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT ID,
           IIF(Column1=LAG(Column1)OVER(ORDER BY ID),'',Column1)AS Column1,
          Column2 
    FROM #t
    )
    UPDATE t
        SET t.Column1=ct.Column1
    FROM #t t
    INNER JOIN CTE ct
        ON ct.ID=t.ID

    SELECT * FROM #t
```

We can update using Subquery too

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.Column1=Dt.Column1
FROM #t t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ID,
           IIF(Column1=LAG(Column1)OVER(ORDER BY ID),'',Column1)AS Column1,
          Column2 
    FROM #t
    )Dt
ON Dt.ID=t.ID
```

Result,Demo:http://rextester.com/MLR80836

```
ID  Column1 Column2
--------------------
1     x       a
2             b
3             c
4     y       d
5             e
6             f
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to update the actual information, but you can express this as by using `SELECT` statement

```
select ID, 
      (case when row_number() over (partition by Column1 order by id) = 1 
            then Column1 
        end) as Column1, 
      Column2
from table t;
```

You can also re-express it by using `subquery`

```
select ID, (case when Seq = 1 then Column1 end) as Column1, Column2
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by Column1 order by id) Seq
      from table
     )t;
```